# Remove single quote from list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have an input string as:

```
result = '"testing","0.8841","642000.0","80.014521","-60.940653","4522126666","1500854400","","1500842014000","name","80.014521","-60.996532","sampledevice","3","name"'

data = result.split("\n")

i = 0
while i < len(data):
    i = i +1 
    dd = data[i].split(',')
    print dd
    break
```

And the corresponding output as:

```
[
  '"testing"',
  '"0.8841"',
  '"642000.0"',
  '"80.014521"',
  '"-60.940653"',
  '"4522126666"',
  '"1500854400"',
  '""',
  '"1500842014000"',
  '"name"',
  '"80.014521"',
  '"-60.996532"',
  '"sampledevice"',
  '"3"',
  '"name"'
]
```

How can I remove the single quotes from each element in the list?

Comment: Note: `while i < len(data):` is not the canonical way to loop through a list, `for data in result.split('/n'): dd = data.split(',') ...` would be more canonical but it looks like `csv`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Treat the text as a row from a CSV formatted file:

```
import csv
import StringIO

result = '"testing","0.8841","642000.0","80.014521","-60.940653","4522126666","1500854400","","1500842014000","name","80.014521","-60.996532","sampledevice","3","name"'
print next(csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(result)))
```

Giving you:

```
['testing', '0.8841', '642000.0', '80.014521', '-60.940653', '4522126666', '1500854400', '', '1500842014000', 'name', '80.014521', '-60.996532', 'sampledevice', '3', 'name']
```

Python's [`StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html?highlight=stringio#module-StringIO) function allows the text to be treated like a file allowing it to be passed to Python's CSV parser which is designed for parsing CSV files in this format. It can then correctly parse the text and return a list of items.

---

The returned data could then be further processed if needed to convert the text into numbers, i.e. integers or floats as appropriate. For example:

```
import csv
import StringIO

def convert(text):
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        return float(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text


result = '"testing","0.8841","642000.0","80.014521","-60.940653","4522126666","1500854400","","1500842014000","name","80.014521","-60.996532","sampledevice","3","name"'
values = [convert(value) for value in next(csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(result)))]

print values
```

This would then return a list as follows:

```
['testing', 0.8841, 642000.0, 80.014521, -60.940653, 4522126666L, 1500854400, '', 1500842014000L, 'name', 80.014521, -60.996532, 'sampledevice', 3, 'name']
```

Comment: What's nice about this is that it allows for commas within the strings as well as separating them.

Answer (score 6):

you need to apply `strip` to remove quotes on both sides of the string.

```
dd = [x.strip('"') for x in data[i].split(',')]
```

that said, your loop seems to have an index issue. Should be rewritten, for instance like this:

```
result = '"testing","0.8841","642000.0","80.014521","-60.940653","4522126666","1500854400"\n"1500842014000","name","80.014521","-60.996532","sampledevice","3","name"'

for line in result.splitlines():
    dd = [x.strip('"') for x in line.split(',')]
    print(dd)
```

at this point, you'd be even better off with

```
dd = ast.literal_eval(line)
```

also perfect usage of `csv` module with a `list` as input (no need to pass a file handle) (don't pass a `string`, though, as it yields some strange effects)

```
import csv
for row in csv.reader(result.splitlines()):
    print(row)
```

all resulting in:

```
['testing', '0.8841', '642000.0', '80.014521', '-60.940653', '4522126666', '1500854400']
['1500842014000', 'name', '80.014521', '-60.996532', 'sampledevice', '3', 'name']
```

Answer (score 6):

literal_eval is good solution for this issue

```
import ast
dd = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in data]
```

Comment: This is the best answer for simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

*Replace* the double quotes before *splitting*:

```
>>> result.replace('"', '').split(',')
['testing', '0.8841', '642000.0', '80.014521', '-60.940653', '4522126666', '1500854400', '', '1500842014000', 'name', '80.014521', '-60.996532', 'sampledevice', '3', 'name']
```

Comment: NMDV but if the string has quotes in it there's a problem. Of course, with OP attempt, if the string has a comma in it, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True, but those are double quotes not single quotes. Double quotes within a string in everyday grammar is rare, if non-existent.

Answer (score 2):

First: You don't have single quotes in output string. What do You have is string which is quoted with double quotes (possibly for storing in `csv` file). Single quotes You see in output are actually determining the string. So:

```
'"some_string"'
```

is actually

```
"some_string"
```

Second: if You want to remove double quotes, You can do:

```
for item in data.split(","):
    print(item.strip('"'))
```

Look at the following statements, it should be more clear:

```
item = '"some_string"'
other_item = 'some_string'
some_other_item = "some_string"

print(item) # --> "some_string"
print(other_item) # --> some_string
print(some_other_item) # --> some_string

print(item, other_item, some_other_item) # --> ('"some_string"', 'some_string', 'some_string')
```

Comment: yes @Fejs the result exactly as csv file. thanks for suggestion. its very helpful

Answer (score 2):

While statement is weird. Doesn't he want to delete single quotes? Why does everyone post answers which delete double quotes.

Here is my suggestion:

```
result = '"testing","0.8841","642000.0","80.014521","-60.940653","4522126666","1500854400","","1500842014000","name","80.014521","-60.996532","sampledevice","3","name"'

data = result.split("\n")

s = str(data)[2:-2] #Convert to a string, and delete [' and ']
for dd in s.split(','):
    print dd
```

Or in a simpler way, this would make the same thing:

```
for dd in result.split(','):
    print(dd)
```

The result:

```
"testing"
"0.8841"
"642000.0"
"80.014521"
"-60.940653"
"4522126666"
"1500854400"
""
"1500842014000"
"name"
"80.014521"
"-60.996532"
"sampledevice"
"3"
"name"
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre actually Alperen has a point - due to the way the OP has described the problem...

Comment: @coder if you say so. Too tired to try to understand. I just edited "cannot comment" because it's an actual answer.

Comment: *Doesn't he want to delete single quotes?* You probably have not realised that `'\n'` is the same as `"\n"` but `'"\n"'` (double quote inside) is not the same as `"'\n'"` (single quote inside). In the OP's case, the double quote is included as part of the string, while the single quotes are there to demarcate the string literal. So your `"testing"` is the same as our `'testing'`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I agree, of course they are different, the thing is that the way OP has described the problem can't make me consider Alperen's answer wrong... that the 'hi' is same as "hi" is another fact

Comment: @coder Not saying it's wrong. Just trying to clear up the confusion with removing `"` or `'` :)

Comment: I would comment and ask if I could, but my reputation wasn't enough. Then, I asked and answered. Thanks for edit.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye You are right, it doesn't matter " or ' in Python, but it matters in speaking and in some others. He says single quotes especially.